# Ansible INI lookup plugin gives ['<element>'], instead of <element>

Tags: regex, ansible, lookup, ansible-2.x

I have a **users.ini** file having below content:

```
[integration]
# My integration information
user=gertrude
pass=anotherpassword
```

I am trying to fetch the value in my below yml file using lookup plugin for INI:

```
- hosts: "{{vnf_ip}}"
  connection: local
  tasks:
    debug: msg="User in integration is {{ lookup('ini', 'user section=integration file=users.ini') }}"
```

But I am getting output as

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.10.10.10] => {
    "msg": "User in integration is ['gertrude']"
}
```

**Instead of ['gertrude'] it should simply be gertrude.**

How to get **gertrude** simply????

Comment: And you are 100% sure you execute the play exactly as you posted in the question? Besides `debug` module is not the best way to test the values. Use `copy` with `content` and check the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Ansible version do you use? On modern 2.3.2 it works as expected and returns just `gertrude`.

If you can't upgrade, you can use `first` filter to get an element from your resulting list:

```
{{ lookup('ini', 'user section=integration file=users.ini') | first }}
```

Comment: I am using Ansible 2.3.2.0 only.